# Get the index of clicked ObservableCollection item in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, observablecollection

This may be an easy question but I have looked around for the answer nearly an hour. So here it goes:

I have an ObservableCollection of numbers, all are 10 and they are shown as buttons. When one from left is clicked, it will decrease it's value and increase the value on the right.

In View, it is defined as below:

```
<UniformGrid x:Name="Nums" Grid.Row="1" Rows="1">
                <local:Nums="{Binding Numbers[0]}" Stroke="Red" Click="Button_Clicked" />
                <local:Nums="{Binding Numbers[1]}" Stroke="Red" Click="Button_Clicked" />
                <local:Nums="{Binding Numbers[2]}" Stroke="Red" Click="Button_Clicked" />
                <local:Nums="{Binding Numbers[3]}" Stroke="Red" Click="Button_Clicked" />
                <local:Nums="{Binding Numbers[4]}" Stroke="Red" Click="Button_Clicked" />
                <local:Nums="{Binding Numbers[5]}" Stroke="Red" Click="Button_Clicked" />
</UniformGrid>
```

Numbers is an ObservableCollection and has the necessary PropertyChangedEvent inside the viewmodel.

```
private ObservableCollection<int> numbers = new ObservableCollection<int>() { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 };
        public ObservableCollection<int> Numbers
        {
            get => Numbers;
            set
            {
                if (value != Numbers)
                {
                    Numbers = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Numbers)));
                }
            }
        }
```

When the button is clicked it triggers the View but I don't know how to get which value and index of the ObservableCollection is clicked?

```
using NumberChanger.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace NumberChanger.Views
{

    public partial class NumberChanger : UserControl
    {
        NumberChangerViewModel numberChangerViewModel = new NumberChangerViewModel();
        public NumberChangerViewModel()
        {
            
            this.DataContext = numberChangerViewModel;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(numberChangerViewModel.Numbers);
            
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Added Nums class

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace NumberChanger.Views
{

    public partial class Nums : Button
    {
      

        public int Nums
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(NumsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NumsProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty NumsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Nums),
            typeof(int),
            new PropertyMetadata(0)
        );

        public Nums()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Nums` class? Perhaps you can utilize its `Tag` property to store index number and then  check it in `Button_Clicked` event hander casting the sender to your `Nums`.

Comment: I do not know what is Nums class. But i would use regular Button with the 'Command' and 'CommandParameter' attributes:

`<Button Content="ButtonText" 
Command="{Binding Command}"
 CommandParameter="{Binding Path=.}" >`

Comment: @bazsisz Added nums class

Comment: @emoacht Added nums class

Comment: "*When one from left is clicked, it will decrease it's value and increase the value on the right*" - what does left and right mean here? You should take a look at the MVVM pattern and implement the logic in a view model instead of a control.

Comment: Its out of scope actually, just a brief information about the program I'm writing @Clemens

Comment: Also note that neither `<local:Nums="{Binding ...}"` nor the dependency property declaration does actually compile. Besides that, you may simply pass the current index to another dependency property.

Comment: @Clemens they are compiling what error are you getting? Ofc I didnt put the whole project's xaml there

Comment: There can't be a Nums property in a Nums class (Compiler Error CS0542), and `<local:Nums=...` is invalid XML/XAML. Please try your code samples before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a not unique collection of int (value type).. there is no possibility to find index in collection by value.
You can find index of clicked control - it will be same as index value in the ObservableCollection in your case.

```
using NumberChanger.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace NumberChanger.Views
{

    public partial class NumberChanger : UserControl
    {
        NumberChangerViewModel numberChangerViewModel = new NumberChangerViewModel();
        public NumberChangerViewModel()
        {
            
            this.DataContext = numberChangerViewModel;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // button inside your local:Nums
            var button = sender as Button;

            // index of control in the UniformGrid which is related to the index in collection
            int index = this.Nums.Children.IndexOf(button); 

            Console.WriteLine(index); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(control.Parent); gives CS1061 compiler error, control does not have an accessible parent. Also where does the childElement come from?

Comment: I assume that local:Nums is UserControl.. may be it derived from some other type?

Comment: added nums class to question

Comment: ok.. in such case no need use logicalTreeHelper. Changed answer.